# MS Small Basic: setting a TextBox to read-only

Tags: smallbasic

Anyone happen to know if it's possible to set a TextBox to read-only in MS Small Basic? There doesn't seem to be any way to set any properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, But its kinda cheating.

```
Textbox = Controls.AddTextBox(20,20)

While 1 = 1
Program.Delay(5)
Controls.SetTextBoxText(Textbox,"Text Here")
EndWhile
```

As you can see, its not the cleanest way of doing in it. But SB hasn't added a command for read only and this works great.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
controls.settextboxtext(control,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that should give you 90% of what you are looking for. There are two text boxes, a locked one with the text color of gray, and an editable one with the text color of black. When the lock button is pressed, the editable box is hidden, the locked one is shown and updated with the current text. To keep from interfering with the rest of the program, the timer event (which runs in itself own thread) is used to lock the text in place. This is all controlled by the editable variable.

The SmallBasic import code for this example is: **PNJ462**

Enjoy!  :-)

```
GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = "darkgray"
Textboxlocked = Controls.AddTextBox(20,20)
Controls.HideControl(Textboxlocked)
GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = "black"
Textbox = Controls.AddTextBox(20,20)
Controls.SetTextBoxText(Textbox,"Hello World")
lock = Controls.AddButton("Lock",20,50)
unlock = Controls.AddButton("Unlock", 130,50)
Controls.ButtonClicked = onButtonClick

Timer.Interval = 10
Timer.Tick = whenTickTocks

Sub whenTickTocks
  If editable = "False" then
    Controls.SetTextBoxText(Textboxlocked,holdtext)
  EndIf
endsub

Sub onButtonClick
  If Controls.LastClickedButton = lock Then
    editable = "False"
    holdtext = Controls.GetTextBoxText(Textbox)
    Controls.SetTextBoxText(Textboxlocked,holdtext)
    Controls.ShowControl(Textboxlocked)
    Controls.HideControl(Textbox)
  Else
    editable = "True"
    Controls.ShowControl(Textbox)
    Controls.HideControl(Textboxlocked)
  EndIf
EndSub
```